# Change layout when screen is rotated and maintain activity state in android

Tags: android, android-orientation

I'm not using configChanges attribute to my activity in manifest as I need to show a different layout for landscape mode. And saving few primitive data values in onSaveInstanceState() method and getting back in Bundle of onCreate(). 
Here are my issues :

1. On click of a button I need to post data to server(using Volley for this). I'm showing a progress dialog during the server communication. App is force closing If I change the device orientation when progress dialog is shown. How can I handle progress dialog state during orientation change? If I use configChanges in manifest, its not force closing but a different layout is not being shown. Please guide me.
2. I need to show different layout for android tablets only. The screen should not get rotated in other phones. Is there a way to specify configChanges for only other phones? How do I do this?

Comment: Asked a bazillion times: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving Activity state in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)

Comment: "How can I handle progress dialog state during orientation change?" -- use a `DialogFragment`. "I need to show different layout for android tablets only. The screen should not get rotated in other phones" -- "phones" and "tablets" are marketing terms, not technical ones. Please explain **completely and precisely** what the difference is, in your mind, between a "phone" and a "tablet". IOW, if you were handed 1000 Android devices, how would you decide which are "phones" and which are "tablets"?

Comment: to handle an activity state using saved instance state bundle check http://www.quicktips.in/handling-activity-state-using-saved-instance-state-bundle/

Answer (score 1):

You should probably add this in your manifest file first (note the `configChanges`):

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Then override these two methods and do what you want with the data inside `onSaveInstanceState()`, `onRestoreInstanceState()`.